# (React Native) lock screen in landscape

Tags: react-native

I'm a newbie in React Native and I cannot find a way to lock the view of a page in landscape mode.
Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You want to have the app always be in landscape mode?
Android or iOS?

There is a hardware mode that allows you to rotate your simulator.
If you want to use lock the app in landscape there is a way using a node module.
The below link should help.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation

Answer (score 2):

Install: npm install react-native-orientation --save

in AppDelegate.m
Add these two lines:

```
#import "../../node_modules/react-native-orientation/iOS/RCTOrientation/Orientation.h"

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return [Orientation getOrientation];
  }

componentDidMount(){


     Orientation.lockToLandscape();  


 }
```

Comment: how to do this in android?

Comment: componentDidMount(){


     Orientation.lockToLandscape();  


 }